# Spring Security stateleless JWT authentication - How to get other jwt fields?

Tags: jwt, spring-security-oauth2

We have a microservice architecture using JWT to authenticate between services. I'm looking to grab more fields out of the JWT easily. Currently really just the authorities are exposed directly by Spring Security.

Example JWT that our edge service/API gateway creates to pass to downstream services (some fields are custom for our app):

```
{
  "projectId": "project1",
  "group": "client",
  "iss": "login.company.com",
  "aud": "company.com",
  "sub": "testguy",
  "exp": 1461074284992,
  "projectRoleId": "ADMINPAG",
  "contentAccessGroupId": "CAG1",
  "authorities": [
    "client",
    "PROJECT_ADD_USER",
    "PROJECT_ADD_CAG",
    "PROJECT_DOCUMENT_VIEW",
    "PROJECT_EDIT_CAG",
    "PROJECT_LIST_USERS",
    "PROJECT_SEARCH"
  ],
  "user_name": "test@company.com"
}
```

It was surprisingly easy to get this working with Spring Boot:

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:1.3.1")
compile('org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:2.0.8.RELEASE')
compile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-jwt:1.0.3.RELEASE')
```

1) Annotate application class

```
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class MyApp {
```

2) Add property to application.yml to configure ignored paths and the JWT key:

```
security:
  basic:
    enabled: false
  oauth2:
    resource.jwt.keyValue: itsasecret
  ignored:
    - /
    - /swagger-ui.html
    - /webjars/**
    - /swagger-resources
    - /swagger/**
```

This results in the user being automatically logged in upon detection of the JWT. I can assert on their permissions with `@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('PROJECT_SEARCH')")` just fine.

The only thing left is I want to be able to grab other fields from the JWT (such as the "sub" - user id). This info seems to be stored in the OAuth2AccessToken#getAdditionalInformation() field. A custom UserDetails implementation would work fine here, but I'd want to be able to create the UserDetails from the JWT directly, not via a UserDetailsService (which creates one based on username).

My primary goal with this is to be able to reference some of these JWT fields from a PreAuthorize annotation, to assert that the current user's ID is the same one passed in the "userId" argument, for example. If at all possible I'd love it if the config changes that are required for this can be isolated to an AutoConfiguration class in a shared module, so we don't have to touch all of our services. The structure of the JWT itself is 100% flexible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found a solution on the Spring Cloud Docs.

What I wanted here was a JwtAccessTokenConverterConfigurer.

The class below is auto detected and will make a custom OAuth2Authentication object for you once the JWT is read:

```
@Component
public class JwtConverter extends DefaultAccessTokenConverter implements
        JwtAccessTokenConverterConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configure(JwtAccessTokenConverter converter) {
        converter.setAccessTokenConverter(this);
    }

    @Override
    public OAuth2Authentication extractAuthentication(Map<String, ?> map) {
        OAuth2Authentication auth = super.extractAuthentication(map);
        MyAppCustomUserDetails details = new MyAppCustomUserDetails();
        //populate details from the provided map, which contains the whole JWT.
        auth.setDetails(details);
        return auth;
    }
}
```

The only thing to note here is that my custom user details object takes an extra hop to get to. It is actually created as a field on the default user details object, called decodedDetails. I just made a custom method argument resolver to aid in retrieving that:

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnBean(JwtConverter.class)
public class WebConfigurer extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
        argumentResolvers.add(currentUserHandlerMethodArgumentResolver());
        super.addArgumentResolvers(argumentResolvers);
    }

    @Bean
    public HandlerMethodArgumentResolver currentUserHandlerMethodArgumentResolver() {
        return new HandlerMethodArgumentResolver() {
            @Override
            public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter) {
                return parameter.getParameterType().equals(MyAppCustomUserDetails.class);
            }

            @Override
            public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter, ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer, NativeWebRequest webRequest, WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception {
                return ((OAuth2AuthenticationDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getDetails()).getDecodedDetails();
            }
        };
    }

}
```

This just allows you to pass your custom user details in as an argument to your controllers and have it be automatically populated from the JWT:

```
@RequestMapping("/currentUser")
public UserInfoResponse getCurrentUser(MyAppCustomUserDetails user){
//do stuff
}
```